# How can I get ID after creating mysql row in Vue - Express

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, sequelize.js

I have question about getting Id from Sequelize.create. I have one database named Cases, there I'm storing whole Cases created by users. Then, I have database CasesImages, where I'm storing images that belongs to cases.

Case model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Case = sequelize.define('Case', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    caseName: DataTypes.STRING,
    constructionSite: DataTypes.STRING,
    createdBy: DataTypes.STRING,
    dateOfDiscovery: { 
        type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        get: function() {
            return moment(this.getDataValue('dateOfDiscovery')).format('DD.MM.YYYY')
        }},
    dateOfRemoval: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    responsible: DataTypes.STRING,
    howManyDiscoveries: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    placeOfDiscovery: DataTypes.STRING,
    text: DataTypes.TEXT,
    sanction: DataTypes.STRING,
    forCompany: DataTypes.STRING,
    priority: DataTypes.STRING,
})

Case.associate = (models) => {
    Case.hasMany(models.caseimages, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'images'});
};

return Case }
```

CaseImage model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const CaseImage = sequelize.define('CaseImage', {
    fileName: DataTypes.STRING,
    mimeType: DataTypes.STRING,
    caseId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'Cases',
            key: 'id',
        }
    },
    path: DataTypes.STRING
})

CaseImage.associate = (models) => {
    CaseImage.belongsTo(models.cases, {foreignKey: 'id', as: 'case'});
  };

return CaseImage;}
```

I can create new Case and then use that ID to add picture. Also, In my express app I have working method that will first create Case, save it, return id of that case and then send image to second db. I tested this using postman and it was working.
You can see that method here:

```
async postImageWithCase (req, res) {
    try {
        Case.create({
            caseName: req.body.caseName,
            constructionSite: req.body.constructionSite,
            createdBy: req.body.createdBy,
            dateOfDiscovery: req.body.dateOfDiscovery,
            dateOfRemoval: req.body.dateOfRemoval,
            responsible: req.body.responsible,
            howManyDiscoveries: req.body.howManyDiscoveries,
            placeOfDiscovery: req.body.placeOfDiscovery,
            text: req.body.text,
            sanction: req.body.sanction,
            forCompany: req.body.forCompany,
            priority: req.body.priority
        })
        .then((result) => {
            const newId = result.id;
            return newId;
        })
        .then((newId) => {
            const checkId = Case.findOne({ where: {id: newId }});

            if (checkId == null) {
                res.status(400).send({ message: 'Prípad so zadaným ID sa nenašiel.'});
                return;
            }

            CaseImage.create({
                fileName: req.file.originalname,
                mimeType: req.file.mimetype,
                caseId: newId,
                path: req.file.path,
            })
            
            res.status(201).send({ message: 'Zistenie bolo úspešne vytvorené aj s fotografiou.'});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).send({ message: 'Nepodarilo sa pridať zistenie s fotografiou.'});
        })
     } 
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'Nepodarilo sa pridať fotografiu, skúste to neskôr.'})

    }
},
```

Here you can also see my Express route setup:

```
app.post('/api/v1/cases/:id/images',
  upload.single('file'),
  CaseImagesController.postImageWithCase)
```

Problem is, that I don't know how to get that ID in my Vue app. I have method, that create new case and then it try to also send image by that new caseId, but it is not working for me. [Error that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNKE6.png)

Also, here you can see my Vue.js method.

```
async submitCaseWithPhotos() {
  const bozpCase = new FormData();
    bozpCase.append('file', this.file);
    bozpCase.append('caseName', this.caseName);
    bozpCase.append('constructionSite', this.constructionSite);
    bozpCase.append('createdBy', this.logedUser);
    bozpCase.append('dateOfDiscovery', this.date);
    bozpCase.append('responsible', this.responsible);
    bozpCase.append('howManyDiscoveries', this.howManyDiscoveries);
    bozpCase.append('placeOfDiscovery', this.placeOfDiscovery);
    bozpCase.append('text', this.text);
    bozpCase.append('sanction', this.sanction);
    bozpCase.append('forCompany', this.forCompany);
    bozpCase.append('priority', this.priority);
    CaseImagesService.postImageWithCase(bozpCase)
    .then((response) => {
      this.$emit("close-card");
    })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    this.error = "Failed to submit data - please try again later.";
    });
},
  formatDate (date) {
      if (!date) return null

      const [year, month, day] = date.split('-')
      return `${day}/${month}/${year}`
    },
  async loadConstructions() {
  ConstructionsService.index()
  .then((response) => {
      if(!response.data){
        throw "Error";
      }
      const data = response.data;
      const constructionSites = [];
      for (const id in data) {
        if(data[id].isActive){
          constructionSites.push({
            id: data[id].id,
            constructionSite: data[id].constructionSite,
            isActive: data[id].isActive
          })};
      }
      this.constructionSites = constructionSites;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.error = "Failed to fetch data - please try again later.";
    });
},
```

},

Also here is my Vue.js API call.

```
postImageWithCase(id, bozpCase) {
    return Api().post('cases/' + id + '/images', bozpCase);
},
```

Maybe I'm missing just some small detail or maybe whole function is wrong, but I tried my best and I'm not able to move.

Comment: #1 I can see 3 different artifacts: cases-api (express) , cases-image-api (express) and web (vue). Am I correct?  #2 Do you need the caseId (obtained when case is created) to be used in case-image creation (cases-image-api) ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutly correct. Yes, because when I create new Case, Sequelize create ID for it. I need this ID to assign image to it.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Not yet, I'm still not able to recieve ID in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

The methods in the `sequelize` api that access the database are all asynchronous, so you'll need to use promises with them.  In other words, lines like

```
const checkId = Case.findOne({ where: {id: newId }});
```

and

```
CaseImage.create({
          fileName: req.file.originalname,
          mimeType: req.file.mimetype,
          caseId: newId,
          path: req.file.path,
      })
```

return promises, so you'll have to use `.then` syntax or `async/await` keywords.

Also, `req.file` is null or undefined in your controller.  You probably meant to type `req.body.file.originalname`, instead of `req.file.originalname`.

Otherwise, you could also try adding a line like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req, null, 2));
```

to try logging out the `req` object.  You might find what your looking for under `req.body`, if you're using express.

You could change the code in `postImageWithCase` to something like

```
async postImageWithCase (req, res) {
    try {
        Case.create({
            caseName: req.body.caseName,
            constructionSite: req.body.constructionSite,
            createdBy: req.body.createdBy,
            dateOfDiscovery: req.body.dateOfDiscovery,
            dateOfRemoval: req.body.dateOfRemoval,
            responsible: req.body.responsible,
            howManyDiscoveries: req.body.howManyDiscoveries,
            placeOfDiscovery: req.body.placeOfDiscovery,
            text: req.body.text,
            sanction: req.body.sanction,
            forCompany: req.body.forCompany,
            priority: req.body.priority
        })
        .then((case) => {
            return CaseImage.create({
                fileName: req.body.file.originalname,
                mimeType: req.body.file.mimetype,
                caseId: case.id,
                path: req.body.file.path,
            })
        .then(caseImage => {
            res.status(201).send({ message: 'Zistenie bolo úspešne vytvorené aj s fotografiou.',
                caseId: caseImage.caseId,
                caseImageId: caseImage.id
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(400).send({ message: 'Nepodarilo sa pridať zistenie s fotografiou.'});
        })
     } 
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'Nepodarilo sa pridať fotografiu, skúste to neskôr.'})

    }
},
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried your suggestion.. first problem was with case. I had to use capital Case, because with lowercase I had error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'case'...
Then I tried to use your edited method and I get same error for req.body.file.originalname - still TypeError: Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined

Comment: But when I use postman with my original method - req.file.originalname.. I get status 201 and it works.. only problem is that I don't know how to use it in Vue.